# Most efficient way to get seconds left in this hour

Tags: php, datetime

I need to get the remaining seconds in the actual hour for caching weather-data. What's the most efficient method of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use PHP's time function as follows:

```
<?php
function getSecondsRemaining()
{
    //Take the current time in seconds since the epoch, modulus by 3600 to get seconds in the hour, then subtract this from 3600 (# secs in an hour)
    return 3600 - time() % (60*60);
}
?>
```

This should get you the performance you want.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you out

Comment: I like this one, it's elegant.

Comment: Nice solution Flyingeagle !

Answer (score 1):

Here you go mate:

```
$currentMinute = date("i");
$minuteLeft = 60 - $currentMinute;
$secondLeft = $minuteLeft * 60;
$secondLeft += date("s");
echo $secondLeft;
```

Comment: I thought of that too - but is that really the most efficient way? I'm a performance-nerd so... :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$date = new DateTime("now");
$seconds_left = ( ( 59 - $date->format("i") ) * 60 ) + ( 60 - $date->format("s") );
```